# How to write an AutoIt script that calculate when it ran first time in a day?

Tags: autoit

What would be an AutoIt script that should take the current time?

Comment: Sure it is ;-) what have you tried to do so far? Do you have some non-working code? There are time-related functions in AutoIt and you could just use IniWrite or RegWrite to save some time information. You just check whether you already had saved a time on that specific day and else you can save it for the first time on the first day and delete all times from earlier days. Then just show the already saved time from that day, everytime you run the script... shouldn't be a long script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function based way; formats result nicely and easy to understand:

```
#include <Date.au3>

Global $ini = "ini.ini"

If _AlreadyRunToday() Then
    MsgBox(0, "Title", _Format(_Diff()))
Else
    __SetTime()
EndIf
__SetDate()

Func _AlreadyRunToday() ;Checks if the program run today yet
    If IniRead($ini, "Section", "D", "") <> @MDAY _
            Or IniRead($ini, "Section", "M", "") <> @MON _
            Or IniRead($ini, "Section", "Y", "") <> @YEAR Then Return False
    Return True
EndFunc

Func _ReadDate() ;Returns the time when the program run the first time in YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
    Return IniRead($ini, "Section", "Y", "") & "/" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "M", "") & "/" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "D", "") & " " & IniRead($ini, "Section", "H", "") & ":" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "Mi", "") & ":" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "S", "")
EndFunc

Func __SetDate() ;Sets the date the program run the last time
    IniWrite($ini, "Section", "D", @MDAY)
    IniWrite($ini, "Section", "M", @MON)
    IniWrite($ini, "Section", "Y", @YEAR)
EndFunc

Func __SetTime() ;Sets the time of the first instance running that day
    IniWrite($ini, "Section", "H", @HOUR)
    IniWrite($ini, "Section", "Mi", @MIN)
    IniWrite($ini, "Section", "S", @SEC)
EndFunc

Func _Diff() ;Calculates the seconds passed since the first run today
    Return _DateDiff("s", _ReadDate(), _NowCalc())
EndFunc

Func _Format($Seconds) ;Turns seconds to HH:MM:SS
    Local $h, $m, $s
    _TicksToTime($Seconds * 1000, $h, $m, $s)
    ;Return $h & ":" & $m & ":" & $s
    Return StringFormat("%02d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s) ;As suggested by Samoth
EndFunc
```

Comment: So you can remove your function `_2(...)` and replace your Return statement in your `_Format(...)` with `StringFormat("%02d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s)`.